# Why is my JavaFX PathTransition invisible?

Tags: animation, javafx, transition, invisible

I copied some code from the Internet which is similar to the one found on the [official JavaFX sample page](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Animation/Transitions/Path%20Transition):

```
final Rectangle rectPath = new Rectangle (0, 0, 40, 40);
rectPath.setArcHeight(10);
rectPath.setArcWidth(10);
rectPath.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
Path path = new Path();
path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20,20));
path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(380, 0, 380, 120, 200, 120));
path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(0, 120, 0, 240, 380, 240));
PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
pathTransition.setPath(path);
pathTransition.setNode(rectPath);
pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
pathTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
pathTransition.play();
// add the path to a pane:
myPane.getChildren().add(path);
```

Now what I get is just the path but no floating rectangle:
[image]

What do I have to do to make the visualization acutally play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your rectangle (`rectPath`) to your scene, or you will not see it:

```
myPane.getChildren().add(path, rectPath);
```